# Spring Security pass URL parameters to Authentication Provider

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

Is there a way to pass URL parameters to an authentication provider in Spring Security 3?

Our login page will need to receive an email token as a parameter that the authentication system will need to be aware of when it sets the status of the user. Specifically, it will let a user with a correct token log in that would not otherwise be able to.

I have a custom class extending the DaoAuthenticationProvider class. My authentication logic is in that class's authenticate method.

I'm hoping there is some way to pass this data into the authenticate method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could inject the HttpServletRequest object on your authentication provider class:

```
private @Autowired HttpServletRequest request;
```

Now, you should be able to access the request parameters with APIs such as `request.getParameterValues(paramName)`

Comment: The other option is probably the spring way to do it, but this was so simple.

Comment: Why is this the selected answer? HttpServletRequest is not available within the AuthenticationProvider. Trying to access it will yeild "No thread-bound request found" error.

Comment: Dunno the issue you're experiencing. It worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me, @JackB probably you are not including the HTTPServletRequest in the spring security context. Spring context and spring security context are two different concepts

Answer (score 4):

You need to override [`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.setDetails()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html#setDetails%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken%29) and pass extra information to your custom authentication provider via `details` property of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`.

Comment: Other way, which I would recommend, is to inject a custom authenticationDetailsSource in the default login filter.

Comment: Makes more sense than the accepted reply.