# How can I pass variables from URL to spring security custom login form?

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, spring-security

I have an app, that should prefill login form with variables grabbed from URL. My security config:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/", "/home").access("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('MANAGER')")
    .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('MANAGER')")
    .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
    .loginProcessingUrl("/login").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
    .and().rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me").tokenRepository(tokenRepository)
    .tokenValiditySeconds(90*24*60*60).and().csrf().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
}
```

And when I tried to access app with url: `"app.com/home"` 
I'm getting `app.com/login` and of course form is empty
So, I need to be able to get user from his identifier passed with such URL: `app.com/home?user=test1` and pass this user to my custom login form:

But at the moment I can't get it - how can I get this path variable in code, and where can I get it.

Comment: You can map `/login` to a controller method handler which should returns your login page then process in that handler to add what you want in the model then retrieve data in your page.

Comment: Yeah, now all implemented exactly in such way, but user should get on app.com/login page after filter redirecting from app.com?username=test. So the question is how and where to grab this username and save it into the session.

Comment: May be this could help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496125/spring-security-pass-url-parameters-to-authentication-provider

Comment: Actually I've already implement it with my custom OncePerRequestFilter where I firstly scan path (getting it from request), and if there presented parameters that I'm interested in - I'm getting them and add to Session. And in "/login" mapped method set them to model. So - thanks you - you advice was very helpful !